# Slideshow / Carousel not working properly in a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, arguments, slideshow

This JS code is not working properly. What is the reason ?

```
let indexOfSlide = 1; // update me !
show(indexOfSlide);

function liveSlide(n){
   show(indexOfSlide = n); // update me !
}

function plusSlidesItem(n){
   show(indexOfSlide += n);
}

function show(indexOfSlide) {
    let slides_item = document.getElementsByClassName("slides-item");
    let tiny_img = document.getElementsByClassName("tiny-img");
    let i;
    
    if( indexOfSlide < 1){
        indexOfSlide = slides_item.length;
    }
    if( indexOfSlide > slides_item.length){
        indexOfSlide = 1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<slides_item.length;i++){
        slides_item[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for(i=0;i< slides_item.length; i++){
        tiny_img[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
    }

    slides_item[indexOfSlide-1].style.display = "initial";
    tiny_img[indexOfSlide-1].style.opacity = "1" ;
}
```

When indexOfSlide is replaced by n in show() function's argument and in two if statements condition in show() then it works properly. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few code refactoring that could be done here.

```
let indexOfSlide = 1; // update me !

// we might as well use the global variable indexOfSlide instead of
// passing it as a parameter since it is updating at each call
function show() {
    let slides_item = document.getElementsByClassName("slides-item");
    let tiny_img = document.getElementsByClassName("tiny-img");

    if( indexOfSlide < 1 ){
        indexOfSlide = slides_item.length;
    } else if( indexOfSlide > slides_item.length ){
        indexOfSlide = 1;
    }

    // you can merge both the loops since they are
    // iterating over the same index sequence
    for(let i = 0; i < slides_item.length; i++){
        slides_item[i].style.display = "none";
        tiny_img[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
    }

    slides_item[indexOfSlide - 1].style.display = "initial";
    tiny_img[indexOfSlide - 1].style.opacity = "1" ;
}

// calling the show() function after it has been defined
// is how it should be done else it'll throw an error

show();

function liveSlide(n){
   indexOfSlide = n;
   show(); // update me !
}

function plusSlidesItem(n){
   indexOfSlide += n;
   show();
}
```

see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Your code is working well even when I calling show() function at 2nd line. My code and your code have only one difference that my show function is taking argument and yours not. Explain me why this difference producing error ?

Comment: Because the argument `indexOfSlide` inside show() is a local variable and any change to a local variable does not effect the global variable even if it has the same name as the global variable

Comment: so when you changed the value of `indexOfSlide` in the show() function the global variable `indexOfSlide` did not get changed

Comment: check this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#:~:text=A%20function%20defined%20by%20a%20function%20expression%20or%20by%20a%20function%20declaration%20inherits%20the%20current%20scope.%20That%20is%2C%20the%20function%20forms%20a%20closure.%20On%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20a%20function%20defined%20by%20a%20Function%20constructor%20does%20not%20inherit%20any%20scope%20other%20than%20the%20global%20scope%20(which%20all%20functions%20inherit).)